# Google Cloud Trace - See service names on spans - trace view - open telemetry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, open-telemetry, opentracing, google-cloud-trace

question on Google Cloud trace - Trace details view.

I'm seeing all my spans of the trace. Also I added a resource on the open telemetry instrumentation `service.name` and `service.version`. Now, I can see these as labels for each span.

What I want is the possibility to see this `service.name` for example on the timeline gant view, to be able to identify on the span which service the span belongs to, without having to click on the span and see details. Is this possible ? (This is simple in Zipkin and Jaeger, because they have this by default, to the left side of the timeline gant view). Should I add another resource to my spans to accommodate Google Cloud trace to be able to do this? Let me know if anyone has experience with this.. I believe this is basic for tracing visualization.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the example view you're attempting to create?

Comment: How did you view the service.name after setting the resource on opentelemetry?